# $(selector, element) Native JS alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm trying to remove all jQuery from my platform one line at a time.

But I'm having some trouble finding a replacement for this

```
$('[data-attribute="value"]', GenericHTMLElement);
```

I was hoping it would be something simple like

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<div><span data-attribute="value"></span><span data-something-else="1000"></span></div>';
var b = div.childNodes;

var a = b.querySelector('[data-attribute="value"]');
```

But that's not working either. Does have any suggestions for me?

Comment: Try with `document.querySelectorAll('[data-attribute="value"]');`

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by *But that's not working either*?

Comment: `HTMLElement` doesn't have a method called `querySelector`, use `document` instead. Also, to select multiple elements, use `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector

Comment: @evolutionxbox OP is not using `HTMLElement`, I guess. He is fetching some element and using it. My guess is, *HTMLElement* is more of geberic name than type

Comment: @Rajesh, you're correct HTMLElement is a generic name for the element where I wan't to search for the selector in. There's always just ONE data-attribute="value" element so querySelectorAll is not needed. 

But I still get the error 'HTML-Element.querySelector' is not a function.

Comment: You need to define what `HTMLElement` is for us.

Comment: @GísliFreyrSvavarsson Since you have shared only 1 line of code, there are lots of assumptions. Some will be correct, some won't. So for better response, please add some related code. May be, try to create a SO snippet(*Notice `<>` iocn in editor*).

Comment: Is `HTML-Element` or `HTMLElement`? And where are you define it?

Comment: I just added to the question, I hope it's clearer now. 
The reason I use this method is to replace $(ElementAsString);

Comment: @GísliFreyrSvavarsson `childNodes` will give you a list of elements. This list will not have `querySelector`. If you loop over nodes, you should be able to get it though. But, my suggestion is just do `div.querySelector(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented,

> childNodes will give you a list of elements. This list will not have querySelector. If you loop over nodes, you should be able to get it though. But, my suggestion is just do div.querySelector(...)

To be specific, it will be of type [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). This is a collection of nodes. So you cannot run `querySelector` on it. You can either loop over all nodes and do `querySelector` on them or just so this operation on parent div.

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<div><span data-attribute="value">Dummy Text</span><span data-something-else="1000"></span></div>';
var b = div.childNodes;

console.log('Type of childNodes is: ', Object.prototype.toString.call(b))

// getting element using loop over childNodes
for(var i = 0; i<b.length; i++) {
  var el = b[i].querySelector('[data-attribute="value"]');
  el && console.log(el.textContent)
}

// getting element using parent elenent.
var el1 = div.querySelector('[data-attribute="value"]');
console.log(el1.textContent)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand what the first code does. It searches for given selector, limiting it to HTMLElementObject scope. Understanding that we can try to do something similar.

From MSDN example, he is using body element:

```
var el = document.body.querySelector("style[type='text/css'], style:not([type])");
```

They have [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) example with data-attributes, take a look please.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your attempt isn't working is that you're trying to call `querySelector` on a NodeList, which doesn't have a `querySelector` method.

If you try it on a single element, it works fine:

```js
function mySelect(selector, el) {
    return el.querySelector(selector);
}

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<div><span data-attribute="value"></span><span data-something-else="1000"></span></div>';
var b = div.childNodes[0];

console.log(mySelect('[data-attribute="value"]', b));
```

But this makes it so that `mySelect(selector, el)` is nothing more than an alias for `el.querySelector(selector)`.

Presumably, you'd want to be able to evaluate a selector on multiple elements at once, and return multiple results, like jQuery does. In that case, you can do so by making some adjustments:

```js
function flatMap(values, f) {
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], values.map(f));
}

function mySelect(selector, els) {
    return flatMap(els.length ? Array.from(els) : [els], function (el) {
        return Array.from(el.querySelectorAll(selector));
    });
}

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<div><span data-attribute="value">span 1</span><span data-something-else="1000"></span></div><div><span data-attribute="value">span 2</span></div>';

console.log(mySelect('[data-attribute="value"]', div.childNodes));

console.log(mySelect('[data-attribute="value"]', div.childNodes[0]));
```

Comment: I would not suggest using `$` as function name. This can cause conflicts with other libraries.